# Groovy Delegate being called instead of Owner Class

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to create a Groovy class that delegates to a ConfigObject property, while it still has a couple properties of it's own. For some reason I can't get it to work correctly. From the documentation of the `@Delegate` annotation it looks like any methods that are already defined on the owner class should be called and **not** delegated to the delegate property. Is there something special going on here because the ConfigObject class implements the Map interface?

```
class ApplicationProperties {
    @Delegate(excludes = ["clone", "serverName", "serverIpAddress"])
    ConfigObject configData
    String serverName = "foo"
    String serverIpAddress = "bar"
}
```

Calling `applicationProperties.serverName` does not return foo, it will return null because it is delegating to the configData instance variable. I've tried having the specific excludes and not having them, doesn't seem to make a difference. If I set `interfaces = false` then the serverName property works correctly, but nothing else seems to delegate to the ConfigData. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to `applicationProperties.getServerName()` that should evaluate to "foo".

Comment: That works! It looks strange to not use property accessors, but this works correctly. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I understand that the behavior is a little surprising, but it isn't really an issue with Delegate.  You would see the same issue if you write a class which implements Map and also has a method with a name like getServerName.  obj.serverName would call obj.get('serverName'), which is what is happening in your case because ConfigObject implements Map.  Depending on what you are doing, if you don't really need to implement Map you might get away with @Delegate(interfaces=false)

Comment: That's what I figured was happening, thanks for the confirmation. I'll look more at our specific use here and we can decide what alternative is better. Thanks again.